# Javascript-Jquery Geolocation and locationpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

```
$(function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        $('#us2').locationpicker({
            location: {
                latitude: 41.0918692, 
                longitude: 29.0602068 
            }, 
            radius: 0,
            scrollwheel: false,
            inputBinding: {
                latitudeInput: $('#us2-lat'),
                longitudeInput: $('#us2-lon'),
                radiusInput: $('#us2-radius'),
                locationNameInput: $('#us2-address')
            }
        });
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;

        // Binding UI with the widget
        $('#us2').locationpicker({
            location: {
                latitude:  lat, 
                longitude: lon 
            }, 
            radius: 0,
            scrollwheel: false,
            inputBinding: {
                latitudeInput: $('#us2-lat'),
                longitudeInput: $('#us2-lon'),
                radiusInput: $('#us2-radius'),
                locationNameInput: $('#us2-address')
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I did this script. But I have a problem. When I open the result page and I clicked Share the Location option when it asked, Everythings fine It opens that direction on map. But When I didnt share the location It dont show map becouse of it cant find coordinates. When people dont share their location I want to set this coordinates latitude:  41.0918692 , longitude: 29.0602068 as you can see at the code. But I think if(navigator.geolocation) code doesnt work.

Comment: Please share HTML as well